# Start dbms_services on standby database

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql

I'm developing a trigger which starts and stops services when the pdb is open. The point is that my trigger doesn't stop the service if I execute the

```
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ALL SAVE STATE;
```

with some services up. So it gives me the error:

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 3
ORA-44303: service name exists
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SERVICE_ERR", line 21
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SERVICE", line 316
```

Is there any other way to start services on standby database?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER managed_service_start
    AFTER STARTUP ON DATABASE
DECLARE
    pdb_role VARCHAR2(64);
    host VARCHAR2(64);
    pdb_name VARCHAR2(64);
    rw_service VARCHAR2(64);
    ro_service VARCHAR2(64);
    rw_up VARCHAR2(1);
    ro_up VARCHAR2(1);
BEGIN
    SELECT database_role INTO pdb_role FROM v$database;
    SELECT host_name INTO host FROM v$instance;
    SELECT Upper(sys_context ('userenv', 'con_name')) INTO pdb_name FROM dual;
    SELECT pdb_name || '_RW' INTO rw_service FROM dual;
    SELECT pdb_name || '_RO' INTO ro_service FROM dual;
    -- validate that services are up. if they are down the variable will be null.
    SELECT max('Y') INTO rw_up FROM v$services WHERE name = rw_service;
    SELECT max('Y') INTO ro_up FROM v$services WHERE name = ro_service;
    IF pdb_role = 'PRIMARY' THEN
        IF (rw_up IS NULL) THEN
            DBMS_SERVICE.START_SERVICE(rw_service);
        END IF;
        IF (ro_up = 'Y') THEN
            DBMS_SERVICE.STOP_SERVICE(ro_service);
        END IF;
    ELSE
        -- IF host IN ('host_name1','host_name2') THEN
        IF host LIKE '%de%' THEN
            IF (ro_up IS NULL) THEN
                DBMS_SERVICE.START_SERVICE(ro_service);
            END IF;
            IF (rw_up = 'Y') THEN
                DBMS_SERVICE.STOP_SERVICE(rw_service);
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF (rw_up = 'Y') THEN
                DBMS_SERVICE.STOP_SERVICE(rw_service);
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
/
```