# Oracle - stop dbms_service

Tags: oracle, dbms

I need to stop read-write service on standby so is there a way to lock connection within a specific service or to set a service as read-only?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of Oracle?  what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Oracle 19, the problem is that I don't want to have read-write service up on the standby and the trigger which should do it fails.

Comment: You don't normally manage a standby with triggers. Please provide more information:  are you using Dataguard?  what is the output of opening a command line and entering dgmgrl SHOW CONFIGURATION

Comment: The dataguard status is correct my error with triggers are here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/240293/start-dbms-services-on-standby-database?noredirect=1#comment473951_240293